# Is this an EWW bug?

Tags: eww

I have a big html file with internal links.
When following internal links, eww.el reloads the entire file.
Is it a known bug or is there a work-around?

Comment: I'm mostly sure that's a bug which has been fixed already.  Which version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: I use emacs 27.2

Comment: Do you have an example URL for reproducing this?  I'm not observing this problem in 27.2 (but I do have a vague recollection of seeing it come up in the bugs list).

Comment: I use eww for browsing local html files, so it is difficult to give a url.
Do you have a link to a related emacs issue?

Comment: Nope; I looked but couldn't find it.  Are you saying this happens *only* with local files, and not for online URLs?  Or only in certain cases?!  I presume it'll be easy to provide an example (either a minimal html file, or a URL) if it's consistent behaviour.

Comment: According to a redditor, the bug should have been fixed in the upcoming 29